# input values into multiple tables where the index of one table creates an entry into the secondary table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a SQL query that input data into multiple tables.

One of the tables has relationship with a separate table, that creates a new entry (I think). I want some of the data to go to this new column in that other table.

The first table is like this,

```
  substancedetails
    - id
     - etc
```

The second table is like

```
Substance Timing
 - substance id
 - time
```

Usually I would insert like this,

```
INSERT INTO substancedetails (xxx,...) 
VALUES(
'xxx',
...)
INSERT INTO SubstanceTiming (x,...) 
VALUES(
'xxx',
...)
;
```

How can i add it against the proper id?

#### This is my latest attempt, it's currently failing unfortunately.

```
WITH i AS (
      INSERT INTO substancedetails (user_id, substance,  duration, planneddose)
          VALUES('xxxx', 'tea',8,'tealeaf')
          RETURNING *
     )
INSERT INTO scheduledtime (substancetiming , time) 
    SELECT id, '08:00 AM',
    FROM i
INSERT INTO scheduledtime (substancetiming , time) 
    SELECT id, '12:00 PM',
    FROM i
INSERT INTO scheduledtime (substancetiming , time) 
    SELECT id, '16:00 PM',
    FROM i;
```

I'm trying to insert for the substance each time I will have that tea, not currently working :(

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: postgres, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `returning` clause:

```
WITH i AS (
      INSERT INTO substancedetails (xxx, ...) 
          VALUES('xxx', ...)
          RETURNING *
     )
INSERT INTO SubstanceTiming (substanceid, x, ...) 
    SELECT id, 'xxx', ...
    FROM i;
```

The use of a CTE with an `insert`/`update`/`delete` is a convenient Postgres enhancement of SQL that allows multiple changes in a single statement.

Comment: Will this create multiple new records with each of the new dosage times (so 3 new rows if the timing is say , [10:00am,12:00pm,4:00pm?]

Comment: @LeCoda . . . This answers the question asked here.  If you have a new question, then ask it as a new question.  If the first query inserts more than one row, the second will insert the same number of rows.